# Get name of subdirectories within Reference Folder ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, reference-folders

I need to ask is there is any way to fetch the name or the path of the folders/subdirectories with in the Reference folder.

I have figured out the way to get the path of the files(.png) in Array within a reference folder but I am curious that is there any way to find the folder also ???

Comment: Yes you saved my loads of time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this where you can pass your directory name as `documentsURL`

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSURL *documentsURL = [paths lastObject];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:documentsURL includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
    errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"[Error] %@ (%@)", error, url);
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }];

    for (NSString* file in enumerator) {
        NSLog(@"File %@",file);
    }
```